# Not able to receive ether onto MetaMask account

Tags: go-ethereum, ether, metamask

I've installed MetaMask, connected to Ethereum Main Net and created an account. Then I copied the address of the account (did "Copy address to clipboard") and sent it to the person who was going to send me some ether. However he failed to transfer it, he was told that the address that I gave him doesn't exist or something.

I'm new to the crypto world and just need to get that Ethereum thing. What am I doing wrong? I've followed MetaMask tutorial step by step. Do I need to register that account, or activate it somewhere else, after I create it in MetaMask?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should not need to "register" or "activate" your account once it's created in Metamask. Make sure you are copying your *whole* address and not just part of it. In Metamask, the first part of your public address is displayed under your account name, and looks like `0x12345...` That's just the first few characters of the address, not the whole thing.

Click the "..." icon to the right of your account name and choose "Copy address to clipboard". Then paste that into a message to your friend. What you paste in should be 40 characters long (not including the `0x` in front; e.g. `0x1234567890123456789012345678901234567890`).

Comment: That's what I was doing (good to know that I'm not exactly that dumb). So do you say that what I did (if I indeed did what I say I did), should be enough?

Comment: Btw, it is really confusing that accounts created for test networks do not disappear when I actually switch the network. I even suspected that problematic account was created on test network. Does it even matter?

Comment: If that's what you did, the problem may be on your friend's end. If you share your public address here, more of us can double check. What network you were connected to when you created the account should not matter; the private key will work on all networks

Comment: This is the address: 0x041Dc022161Af724C301f5085160Cb1c5e2D776e. But I have a question now - if it should work on all networks. I should have been able to send some ether to it from the testnet as well? It didn't let me.

Comment: @jayarjo that address [is a valid address](https://etherscan.io/address/0x041Dc022161Af724C301f5085160Cb1c5e2D776e), and I was just able to transfer .001 ETH to you using my Metamask account. So you've done everything correct; the person who failed to transfer funds to you at that address is doing something wrong.

Comment: Hmm... awkward. I see it on my account in MetaMask now. That rises the set of whole new questions I guess... :/ Thanks for help! What's your account. I will transfer it back (before it becomes equivalent of lambo price you know).

Comment: If you want to send it back, see if you can figure out from the transaction history where I sent it from (another learning experience!); that's my main Metamask account ;)

Comment: Hm... looks like I can't send back the same sum... I thought the thing was comission free..? I guess I need to familiarize myself with it a bit deeper.